# Is it dangerous to have unused Windows 10 Defender Firewall rules active?

Tags: firewalls, windows-10

I recently discovered that a bunch of games I've installed in the past (from legit sources) have activated many Windows Defender firewall rules viewable from *wf.msc*. Some of the games I have since uninstalled, so I don't know why the rules are still there. Some of them seem to be pretty permissive.

I'd like to know if these pose any sort of a threat to my computer though. Are these old rules security holes something that could be/has been exploited in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rules are specific to applications, **no not really**. Where exploitation can happen is when something listens on that port and the rule allows it. Ergo if nothing is listening, nothing can happen. So those games being uninstalled doesn't affect your security in a negative way if the rules are tied to the specific application(s) because nothing is listening on that port with that process identification pattern to allow action through the Windows Firewall.

For that rule to be exploited you'd already have to be so completely taken over that nothing could stop the virus/attacker at that point.

If the rule is NOT tied to a specific application, yes, it could be exploited if you download a virus. However for something to exploit the rule, the program would find that open port, listen on the port, and report home. Usually that behavior triggers antivirus. However at that point you've already gotten a virus that is attempting to find open unsecured ports it can listen with. Which means you already have a virus. Which is bad for other reasons.

It is however perfectly safe to delete those rules if that software is no longer around. It just means if you ever reinstall it it will ask for the permission again.

Answer (score 1):

Very few applications will remove Windows firewall rules, so that is common to see rules for uninstalled applications. Depending on how the rule is written it may not be any risk at all having them there, but it is always be best to remove unused rules.

The risk would be based on how specific or general the rule was. The more specific the rule (for example, app name and port), the less of a risk it would be. A more general rule would be more of a risk, but the chances of it actually being exploitable may be pretty low.

Windows firewall can accumulate many rules if you frequently install and uninstall applications, so it is always best to do regular housekeeping to keep things simple and safe.

Comment: It's weird that an apps uninstaller wouldn't remove firewall rules though.